# add metadata field via pandoc lua filter

Tags: filter, lua, yaml, pandoc

I'm processing a markdown document such as

```
---
title: "dummy title"
highlight: "c"
highlighted: 'highlighted'
---     
body text
```

into a highly-customised latex template where, among other things "c" is being highlighted as part of a larger tex macro. One last step is resisting me: the dummy metadata "highlighted" should not have to be specified here, but I can't find a way to generate it in the lua filter below:

```
text = require 'text'
newstring = '\\textit{a,b,c,d}'

function meta_vars (m)
       -- m.highlighted = 'highlighted' -- not working
        highlight = m.highlight
  return m
end

function replace (elem)
      if elem.text == 'highlighted' then
        newstring = newstring:gsub(pandoc.utils.stringify(highlight),
                       '{\\bfseries '..pandoc.utils.stringify(highlight)..'}')
        return pandoc.RawInline("latex", newstring)
        else
        return elem
      end
    end

return {{Meta = meta_vars}, {Str = replace}}
```

with the following custom template

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\title{$title$ -- $highlighted$}
\maketitle
$body$
\end{document}
```

The command to run this example is

```
pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS test.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output test.tex --template _tpl.tex --lua-filter=filter.lua
```

producing, as advertised

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4FOv.png)

How can I get rid off the dummy `highlighted` tag in my YAML header?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand exactly what you're doing with the latex macros here, but the crux of your question seems to be about adding a new metadata element. The line that you have commented out with `--not working` seems to work fine for me. You might want to explicitly set the type with

```
m.highlighted=pandoc.MetaString('highlighted')
```

but I don't think that will change anything.

I also note that as it is written the newstring variable will be modified whenever the word `highlighted` appears in the text. With two lines of `highlighted` the newstring will equal `\textit{a,b,{\bfseries {\bfseries c}},d}`.

Perhaps you could restate your question with the latex macro stuff removed and just focus on what you want the filter to do.